# python script - Scraping Data but not looping and bringing back all results

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to python and need some help
See py script below, it brings back information for one entry but I want it to bring back all items that come up on that URL including on the pages not shown, What needs changing on the below to do that?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/global/uk/Product/ProductList.aspx?
Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=graphics+card&N=-1&isNodeId=1'

uClient=uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = Soup(page_html, 'html.parser')
containers = page_soup.findAll('div',{'class':'item-container'})
for container in containers: 
    brand = container.div.div.a.img['title']

    title_container = container.findAll('a',{'class':'item-title'})
    product_name = title_container [0].text

    price_container = container.findAll('li',{'class':'price-current'})
    Price = price_container[0].text.strip()

    print("brand: " + brand)
    print("product_name: " + product_name)
    print("Price: + " + Price)
```

Comment: please fix your indentation to make it correctly readable, in current state it's hard to understand, what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks olisch for replying, I'm new to coding so see the change above, hopefully helps, if you know how to make it bring ball all the contents of the search that would be very helpful.

Comment: If you want to get all 10 pages you need to build a mini crawler. It can be done easily with a  loop.

Comment: Thanks, how do I build a mini crawler?

Comment: Use a for loop : `for i in range(1, 11)`